# java.lang.InstantiationException: my.package.CustomActionListener with non-default constructor

Tags: jsf, serialization, actionlistener, commandbutton

I'm try to generate a commandButton on primefaces 5.1, but I have an error:

Here the xhtml file:

```
<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body styleClass="appDefaultBg">

    <h:form>
        <p:remoteCommand autoRun="true" action="#{bean.pageRender()}" update=":pageElement" />
    </h:form>

    <h:panelGroup id="pageElement">
    </h:panelGroup>

</h:body>
```

Here the bean class:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
@SessionScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

private static final String PAGE_ELEMENT = "pageElement";

private UIComponent page;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    findComponent();
}

public void findComponent() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().invokeOnComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), PAGE_ELEMENT, new ContextCallback() {
        @Override
        public void invokeContextCallback(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
            page = component;
        }
    });
}

public void pageRender() {
    HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();

    Panel panel = new Panel();
    panel.setId("filter");
    panel.setHeader("Header");

    CommandButton customButton = new CommandButton();
    customButton.setValue("Click me!");
    customButton.addActionListener(new CustomActionListener(5));

    panel.getChildren().add(customButton);
    form.getChildren().add(panel);
    page.getChildren().add(form);

}
}
```

Here the CustomActionListener:

```
public class CustomActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private int u;

    public CustomActionListener(int u) {
        this.u = u;
    }

    @Override
    public void processAction(ActionEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
        System.out.println(u);
    }
}
```

The error that I receive when I press the button is:

```
GRAVE: java.lang.InstantiationException: my.package.CustomActionListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.InstantiationException: my.package.CustomActionListener
    at javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver.restore(StateHolderSaver.java:153)
    at javax.faces.component.AttachedObjectListHolder.restoreState(AttachedObjectListHolder.java:158)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1611)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateHolderSaver.restore(StateHolderSaver.java:165)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.restoreDynamicAdd(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.restoreDynamicActions(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:227)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.restoreView(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:395)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:138)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:585)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:150)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:197)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.synapsis.catalina.realm.filter.AlertChangePWDBefore.doFilter(AlertChangePWDBefore.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.synapsis.catalina.realm.filter.SingleLogOnFilter.doFilter(SingleLogOnFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.synapsis.catalina.realm.filter.DefaultUserFilter.doFilter(DefaultUserFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.synapsis.sio.ward.usercontext.controller.filter.UserContextFilter.doFilter(UserContextFilter.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: my.package.CustomActionListener
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:359)
    at javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver.restore(StateHolderSaver.java:150)
    ... 51 more
```

If I remove arguments from constructor i doesn't receive this error. But I need to pass an argument to my CustomerActionListener.
How can I fix?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve (from a functional point of view, not technical)? Since the code example is something I've never seen before.

Comment: What I want to do is to create a page from java code, dynamically.

Comment: Lots of examples for this: http://java.dzone.com/articles/creating-jsf-pages-pure-java... But it looks like you want to do it sort of lazy or rather update a part of the page was loaded (do it via a remote command with an autorun="true"...) Or does the page actually work when not passing the argument? Or do I miss something ?

Comment: thanks for the link. As you can see they create an actionListener so as me. But I need to pass some arguments into the constructor, or in other way. The problem is that if I generate the constructor with arguments I will have the described error, otherwise, with a set method, I can see that the button click action will generate a new ActionListener, and so I lost the setted parameter.

Comment: Did you try `CustomActionListener al = new CustomActionListener();
    al.setU(5);
    customButton.addActionListener(al);`
Or something similar?

(sorry for the formatting... cannot get it right in a comment)

Comment: And don't use 'new CommandButton()' etc...  use FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()..getApplication().createComponent(CommandButton.COMPONENT_TYPE);

Comment: Nothing changes with the createComponent method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the strange design approach (feel free to ask a question on how to properly achieve the concrete functional requirement for which you [possibly incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) thought that this would be the right solution), you can solve it by letting it implement [`Externalizable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html). This is an extension on `Serializable` which allows you to take over the responsibility to serialize properties.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
public class CustomActionListener implements ActionListener, Externalizable {

    private int u;

    public CustomActionListener() {
        // Keep default c'tor alive for serialization.
    }

    public CustomActionListener(int u) {
        this.u = u;
    }

    @Override
    public void processAction(ActionEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
        System.out.println(u);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput output) throws IOException {
        output.writeInt(u);
    }

    @Override
    public void readExternal(ObjectInput input) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        u = input.readInt();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but why did you say that this is a strange approach? I need to design the page dynamically... And for dynamically I mean that a logged Client user, can have the possibility to add some input text, or table, ...
with the definition of this into a specific configuration place.

Comment: Yes, I'm agree with you. But I have to offer this possibility at a logged User. Have you got a better solution to suggest me? Ah.. your solution does work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a default constructor at CustomActionListener (apart from the customized one).

Comment: while this is true, it will cause the ActionListener to be (re-)constructed with a unset value. So he losses the chance to get the "5" inside the event processing.

Comment: Sorry Luis but I can't understand what you mean with:
call an actionListener directly...

Comment: But I want create a page from java code, dynamically.

Comment: why? curiosity.
still... why don't you create a setU(int u) and set it after the constructor

Comment: I did try this solution. But when I press the button, the value is null. This because the CustomActionListener will be created again.

Comment: I'm try this solution because I doesn't know the page content... I have to create it dynamically... in example, a client user, can add some input field by the definition of them in an appropriate structure.

Comment: You mean.. any user can add fields? There are components for that. Creating components in Java is not nice... web designers don't have an easy task..

Comment: Yes, any user can add fields, button and table. Exists a component for that? Can you help me to find the way??

Comment: I agree with @BalusC
This seems a XY problem.

check this: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/collector.xhtml
and this: http://pastebin.com/uaunHXYa